# How to express a type that represents an associative array whose keys determine the type of the value?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types

I'm fairly new to type systems and theory, so I would appreciate some guidance in a problem that sparked my interest.

I would like to understand what type system features are required so a compiler can enforce that a given key will return a value of the same type as the one the key was associated with in the first place.

A practical version of my problem is to declare a Map in TypeScript that allows a developer experience like in the [pseudocode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGwAWBTGBeGYUHcYFl4AHAHgGkAaGANQD4AKASgChmFkUA6CFKegcgBiIEPyoBRAE6SQkgQCV+jFu1TdeAgELxJYmAEYWbRGoDmGoSKUwA9DZjzeAV0lgYAN3gAbJ2igBPIhQAExh4CBgpGUkAYXBoSSdgKFlOVlUucz5+bV1GW3tHKBc3Tx8-QJCwiLAnAFsAIxRJNOMOTiyBAEUnAA9rOxg4uqIASy94KFHwGGbo1qA) below:

```typescript
const cache =  new  Map<K,  V>()

cache.set('Foo',  Error('R'))

cache.set('Bar',  1)

cache.get('Foo')  // Return value typed as Error.
  
cache.get('Bar')  // Return value typed as number.

cache.get('Qux')  // Compilation error.
```

What would the type of `K` and `V` be?

Comment: You can't do it like this. That said, why not just use statically typed variables `Foo`, `Bar`? Anything beyond that scenario is probably undecidable: `if (undecidable condition) { cache.set('A', 1) } else { cache.set('A', 'B') }` - and we don't know what type of `A`'s value should be.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if I try to get `Bar` before it has been set? If you expect a compilation error, then you are not talking about a single type, but instead a sequence of types, where the type changes after each call to the set method. Look into 'strong update' and 'linear types'.

Why not just use a record type?

```
type MyRecord = { Foo : Error, Bar : number }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Could you elaborate on your suggestion of using a record type. The keys are not guaranteed to be just those 2. The keys should be understood as being of any type, but could be constrained to something sensible like any string. I apologize if my question was not clear. Let me know if it should be edited.

Comment: When people want this sort of thing, they are usually trying to initialize a set of typed fields one field at a time. But that is only superficially different from initializing them ``all at once'' as a record. Suppose we define a function whose parameter has your type. (x : YourType) => { return x.get("Bar") }

Comment: What is the function's return type? We can create multiple caches and set "Bar" to values of multiple different types. We can then pass these caches into the above function. In each case it will return a value of a different type, but a function must have *one* return type. That's why what you are talking about is not actually a type at all.

Answer (score 0):

Existential types will do the trick.

Your question is not clear on this point, but as far as I can tell the keys are intended to be strings, and the values can have any type.

The type of `cache.get` is `string → ∃ t . t`, i.e., a function taking a string and return a results of type `t`, for some type `t`.

The type of `cache.set` is `∀ t . string → t → unit`.

Comment: Does this "enforce that a given key will return a value of the same type as the one the key was associated with in the first place"?  It doesn't seem like it, as there is nothing connecting the type of the argument to `cache.set` with the type of the result of `cache.get`.

Comment: That depends on the implementation. You could implement a `cache` which always returns 42. To enforce that the cache works correctly, you need a more expressive formalism, such as dependent types or a specification language. Once you have that it's pretty much the same thing to say "it returns the value that was put in" and "it returns a value of the same type that was put it". In any case, the whole thing is of ill-concived design and one should not be implementing cache this way, but I'd rather not get into a religuous war over this issue.